# sqlite IF statement (use case?)

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using SQLITE. I have a dataset of prices and ticker symbols and I want to groupby ticker symbols only when the prices are the same.

iE)

```
{ticker: "AAPL", price: "12", shares: 1}
{ticker: "AAPL", price: "12", shares: 2}
```

Would be grouped into 3 shares but if prices were not the same they wouldn't be. What is a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```sql
SELECT ticket, price, SUM(shares) AS shares
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ticket, price;
```

The above logic would report all shares falling under the same ticket symbol and price as a single line item in the result set.